# How to use #define in system() in C++?

Tags: c++, grep, c-preprocessor, quotes, system-calls

Please consider the following code :

```
#define LV_INFO(major,minor) lvdisplay -c | grep major':'minor >/root/lvInfo.txt

int main(){
    int major=256,minor=6;
    system(LV_INFO(major,minor));
    return 0;
}
```

But above code does not work as system need command as input parameter with double quotes.

It means,

```
#define LV_INFO(major,minor) "lvdisplay -c|grep major':'minor >/root/lvinfo.txt"
```

But it does not work either. It does not put values of major and minor passed by `main()`.

How do I run above command with given parameters in system call?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If both your values (major and minor) are constants, you can simply stringify the results.

```
#define LV_INFO(major,minor) "lvdisplay -c | grep " STRINGIFY(major) "':'" STRINGIFY(minor) " >/root/lvInfo.txt"
#define MAJOR 256
#define MINOR 6
#define STRINGIFY(a) #a
#define _LV_INFO LV_INFO(MAJOR, MINOR)

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf(_LV_INFO);
    return 0;
}
```

If your values are not constant, through (eg. coming from the command line arguments, this will definitely not work. You'll need to build the string from `sprintf`, for instance.

EDIT: Following your command, here's how you would build your command string using `sprintf` :

```
int main(){
    int major=256,minor=6;
    char command[256];
    sprintf(command, "lvdisplay -c | grep %d':'%d >/root/lvInfo.txt", major, minor);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works fine with constant values. but my program depends on run-time values. So, i tried to pass values from main() and use them in #define as -     #define LV_INFO(major,minor) "lvdisplay -c|grep" #major "':'" #minor ">/root/lvInfo.txt".But again it does not work. it does not take run time values of parameters. it just places string major and minor in command. Please help me to run it with run time values.

Comment: I'm afraid you will not be able to stringify runtime values since stringification happens at compile-time. As I suggested, you should build your command string using `sprintf` or a similar function.

Comment: Can you be more specific about building a string using sprintf and using it in #define?? How to do it exctly?

Comment: Again, your solution works fine. Thanks. I was just hoping for a solution with #define. It would be great if you can suggest anything in that perspective.